# Tomcat 404 requested resource is not available - Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat8

I tried to use Maven for simple Web application

Using LINUX SERVER EC2 Followed the steps in the 
[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_web_application.htm)

1. mvn archetype:generate 
   -DgroupId=com.companyname.automobile 
   -DartifactId=trucks
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
   -DinteractiveMode=false
2. mvn clean package - Build is Success and no issues.
3. Copied the war file to my webapps folder.
4. Restarted my tomcat server but getting error as follows

[image]

JAVA HOME PATH AND MAVEN PATHS:

[image]
ERROR LOG AS FOLLOWS :

Comment: your war is called trucks? under webapps/trucks is index.jsp file?

Comment: Take a look at the tomcat logs. This is an http error meaning that the page you requested doesn't exist, that in a tomcat application means that your context doesn't get up because of some error. This 404 means nothing to us.

Comment: yes @Milaci webapp/trucks/index.jsp.

Comment: and your tomcat was started correctly? Can you post some tomcat log?

Comment: yes I am using tomcat 8 and its running correctly

Comment: and your server port is 8080? i don't understand what should be, if your war is deloy correctly and you have all correctly

Comment: In my  /var/log/tomcat8/lot of log files are there like catalina.2017-03-23.log , host-manager.2017-03-23.log etc.. Yes my port no is 8080 and its for tomcat

Comment: Make another test, shutdown and startup your tomact. and post your catalin log

Comment: Yes I done that.. Its seems in Log nothing logged related to that trucks project

Comment: *After 3 hours debug found that problem is Folder Permission issue in tomcat. It's not able to write on work folder* Thanks lot all your guidelines